# finalize() method

Tags: java

I want to know why its neccessary to write this statement super.finalize() in the following

code.

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {

    try {

        close();

    } catch(Exception e) {

    }

    finally {

        super.finalize();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the finalize method and since you're doing this, you need to call the parents `finalize` method as well. Otherwise it's possible that it didn't close streams or other resources accordingly.

You don't have to call the object's `finalize()` method for sure, but it can produce really nasty bugs when you e.g. copy/paste code to another class or change the parent of the inheritance.

It is wrapped in the finally-block to make sure that it is always called, no matter what happens (e.g. an exception in the close() method).

You should also take a look at the Javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize

Comment: May be it's not necessary: `The finalize method of class Object performs no special action; it simply returns normally. Subclasses of Object may override this definition.`

Comment: *Otherwise it's possible that the object will not be garbage collected at any time.* this is not true at all, finalize is used to manage resources not part of the JVM, itself. The object **will be GC** 'd but any managed resource may not be.

Comment: @erickzetta not always neccessary, but it can produce really nasty bugs when you e.g. copy/paste code to another class or change the parent of the inheritance. It's better to just call it and be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If `close()` throws an exception, then the superclass's finalizer would never be called without the `finally` clause. Although, if the superclass is just an `Object` then it really doesn't matter: according to docs, *The finalize method of class Object performs no special action; it simply returns normally*.